# object shift in blender

Tags: animation, blender

I have two animated objects
Soldier and weapon
Animations are already created, but there is a problem, the weapon is not in the hands of a soldier.
How do you move the weapon along with its entire animation? So that I don't have to edit the whole animation frame by frame

It looks more or less like the picture, as you can see the pickaxe is lower than the hand[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the 3D cursor to objects origin
Now add a new empty to the scene, it should be added at the objects origin
Parent the object to empty
Now move the empty to the desired location and the whole animation will be moved as well

Answer (score 0):

idk how to add new empty to the scene.
I'm trying to do like that:
On. 3D view -> pose mode -> 3d cursor 
what next?